# How does nano have a gui interface on ssh

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I would like to write a python app that manages the ssh screen in a fashion similar to the nano editor on a RPI. Accept input and place output data at fixed locations of the ssh window. Does someone know how this is done?

Comment: This is very broad, but search for "text ui library" and try something out. I _suspect_ that nano uses [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)). Python [supports curses on Unix](https://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#module-curses).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/curses.html#module-curses

The curses module is part of the standard library as of 2.6. It provides an interface to the curses library (note: not installed by default on Windows). On Linux, you should be able to install ncurses to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They draw their interface using ANSI sequences. Python has a built in module to this called curses, which is a binding for the ncurses library.

You can check out [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) and [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html).

If you are willing to use libraries, there are higher level ones like [urwid](http://urwid.org/).